# calling a function from a class inside a namespace?

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-code, namespaces

I wrote a code with a class existing inside a namespace.

This is the header file: As you can see, the class is created inside the namespace, in frileg.h.

```
namespace frileg
{
    class legeplads
    {
    public:
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
        void print();
    };
}
```

Then I also have defined the function print() inside the legeplads.cpp:

```
void frileg::legeplads::print()
{
    std::cout << "pos: {" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << "}" << std::endl;
}
```

but when I run the code in the main function, I get an error: "undefined reference to `frileg::legeplads::print()':"

```
int main(){

    legeplads a;
    a.x = 1;
    a.y = 2;
    a.z = 3;
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you modify your `tasks.json` to have Visual Studio Code compile more than 1 source file into your executable. The default behavior of VSCode is to build only the active file so if you have 2 cpp files and you don't modify your tasks.json expect linker errors.

Comment: how do I do it?

Comment: "command": "C:\\DEV\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g3",
                "-Wall",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },

Comment: which part should be edited?

Comment: The documentation for VSCode explains how to compile with more than 1 source file here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: The `"${file}",` part is the bug. That means compile only the active file.

Comment: I did that, but its not working...

Comment: You may have some other error in addition to the need to change tasks.json  then.  You most likely have to add additional information to your question for anyone to possibly help.

Comment: How do I make it work for the JSON file, I already tried to change it but it just won't work. How do I call a print function to print out a variable defined in a class inside a namespace from the main function?

Comment: I just tested the code in VSCode on Windows 10 and it worked without any errors after adding the necessary includes, fixing `tasks.json` and changing `legeplads a;` to `frileg::legeplads a;` I got output: `pos: {1, 2, 3}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working using the following methods.

1. Create a new folder in VSCode. I named it `SO_66629443_20210315` and put it in my X:\test folder
2. Add the 3 files.
3. Fix the missing includes. `legeplads.cpp` requires `#include <iostream>` and `#include "frileg.h"` and `main.cpp` requires `#include "frileg.h"`
4. Modify `main.cpp` to use the frileg namespace when constructing a; use `frileg::legeplads a;` instead of `legeplads a;`

So at this point the files look like:

main.cpp

```
#include "frileg.h"

int main()
{

    frileg::legeplads a;
    a.x = 1;
    a.y = 2;
    a.z = 3;
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

legeplads.cpp

```
#include "frileg.h"
#include <iostream>

void frileg::legeplads::print()
{
    std::cout << "pos: {" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << "}" << std::endl;
}
```

frileg.h

```
namespace frileg
{
    class legeplads
    {
    public:
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
        void print();
    };
}
```

5. Modify `tasks.json` to compile more than 1 file as the documentation tells you here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson

so the `tasks.json` file looks exactly like:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Note that I am using msys2 for my mingw installation. I installed that using these instructions: https://www.msys2.org/

And finally executing the program in VSCode looked like this:

```
PS X:\test\SO_66629443_20210315>  & 'c:\Users\dresc\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.2.2\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-gtfgey3y.olb' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-l2sggqju.oz3' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-zgahgwi3.zwy' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-0mc3zqbv.bqm' '--dbgExe=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'    
pos: {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: But i did exactly what you did, the code will compile alright, but it won't execute.

Comment: I figured it out, i just pressed the wrong button.

Comment: Its F5 to debug or ctrl-F5 to run without debugging.